# C program output involving pointers

Tags: c, pointers, output

```
 int main()
 {
  int a = 300;    
  char *b = (char *)&a;
  *++b = 2;
   printf("%d ",a);
    return 0;
  }
```

I think the output is 300, but the answer is 556.Can someone please explain it.

Comment: What do you mean "the output is 300, but the answer is 556"?  What is the output if you run your program? Where is "the answer" coming from?

Comment: How about you explain first why you think either value is right or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If it is Little endianess it looks like

```
a = 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0001 | 0010 1100
    |                                                       |
    MSB                                                     b<--points base address
                                                            LSB
```

Next when you do `*++b = 2;` `b` got changed now it points to 
second bytes(bcz `char ptr` increment by `1` byte)  and there you are putting `2`(1st byte data unchanged)

```
a = 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0010 | 0010 1100 => 512 + 44 = 556 
                                                  |         |
                                                  b         LSB
```

Answer (score 0):

The integer value 300 in binary is: `00000001 00101100`. 
It is stored in memory as: `00101100 00000001`.

Result of the expression `*++ptr = 2` makes the memory representation as: `00000010 00101100`.

So the integer corresponding to it is `00000010 00101100 => 556`.

Comment: Your good explanation looks like switching endianess in mid-explanation. I expected `00000010 00101100` instead of `00101100 00000010`.